# Is it possible to get a weak referenced object from id with `WeakMap` or `WeakSet`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to store weak referenced object with its `id` (integer) and get the object later by `id`. And I will expect getting `undefined` or `null` from the `id` once it's GCed.

ES2015 introduces `WeakMap` and `WeakSet`. However they both don't allow primitive types as key and don't allow iteration.

Is it possible to achieve this?

**NOTE:** I'm aware that `WeakMap` and `WeakSet` are weak in keys. I'm asking whether it is possible to implement function mentioned above, via `WeakSet` or `WeakMap` or other ways in JS.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, the weak referenced collections are only for weak *keys*, not weak *values*.

Comment: *weakly referenced keys, not weakly referenced values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to hold an arbitrary reference to an object weakly. There is a proposal to add such an API, but it is not currently possible. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs